# C# error when i start my form

Tags: c#

When i try to start my WindowsFormApplication i get this error -

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception.
```

[image: here is screen]

Im using Visual Studio 2013

My form - http://pastebin.com/9tALtuW5

How can i fix this issue ?

i have already tried these things -
i opened exception setting and checked then unchecked all of the (read it on another thread that it helped a similar issue)

My Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new BlackOpsIICF());
        }
    }
}
```

by the way english isnt my 1st language

Comment: Some code would help.

Comment: @JackHughes Such as ? Sorry im new to this :) - I have no error/warning messages if thats what you mean

Comment: At the very least show your Program.Main method and the constructor of your form.

Comment: I am very sorry but i dont know what those are, once again i am new to this sorry for the inconvenience :)

Comment: Your code? Like...all the stuff you typed up prior to hitting the build button to receive that message?

Comment: Ok, give me a second :)

Comment: Do you really have a form class named `BlackOpsIICF`??? looks like it should be `BlackOpsIIMF` rather

Comment: Yep, its an RTM tool, (ps3 modding) CF means Connection Form :)

Comment: That error usually indicates an exception is thrown in a static constructor (or static field initializer).  Does `BlackOpsIICF` have a static constructor?

Comment: Very sorry but i dont know what a "static constuctor" is, sorry

Comment: Open the `BlackOpsIICF` form and press F7 to view the code.

Comment: ok, what do i do now?

Comment: @Bunny You add it to your question.

Comment: its very large so ill put it on pastebin ?

Comment: @Bunny Just add the constructor. That is, the "function" `public BlackOpsIICF()` and any methods called in it.

Comment: just go here - http://pastebin.com/9tALtuW5

Comment: i dont know what that is sorry

Comment: Ok give me a few minutes, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @Bunny It looks okay. It's probably PS3API that's throwing the exception.

Comment: using SimdiBo2;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using PS3Lib;
using MetroFramework;
using WindowsFormsApplication4;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class BlackOpsIICF : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    {
        public BlackOpsIICF()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

Comment: Sorry, looks very unorganized on my screen

Comment: @cubrr, ok how can i fix that ? :) thanks for responding by the way

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, because has the same exception recently. Try to clean your application settings at:

- c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\YourCompanyName...
- c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\YourCompanyName...

Comment: Just delete these folders. They should be re-generated after next application start

Answer (score 0):

`System.TypeInitializationException` is being thrown when C# can't initialize class. Check static fields and static constructors of `BlackOpsIICF` class or its fields of your custom types.